# How to let user make a choice from a list of fonts, sizes and colors inside the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

Is there any way to let user make a choice from a list of fonts, sizes and colors inside the app? (Xcode/iOS)

Thanks!

Comment: In iOS7 also look into OS level support for font sizes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/preferredFontForTextStyle:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either UITableViews or UIPickerViews, whichever suits your design.

There are frameworks that can help you with that, especially for the color, here's an example:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/color-picker-for-iphone

Worked? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPickerView,
Link For Class Reference Is Here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html